# Elastic Beanstalk deployment fails with 'requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status' - No matching distribution found for pywin32==224

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pywin32, requirements

I'm just trying to get my application running on Elastic Beanstalk - but when I run `eb deploy`, it uploads the code and then the console runs into an error before the app is running.

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...) File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd) CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I check the logs to see where the error is with regard to requirements.txt, and this is what I can see:

```
var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting pywin32==224 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 92))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==224 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 92)) (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for pywin32==224 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 92))
  You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  2019-05-02 07:33:21,688 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

On my virtual env, these are the relevant parts of my requirements.txt

```
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==224
```

I'm running python version 3.7.2, Django version 2.1

I've seen a few threads on this elsewhere, but no definitive answer about what to do...?

Comment: probably because this is running on a Linux machine?

Comment: But why is it trying to install it? I have it in my requirements only because when I do pip show pypiwin32, I get this:

Comment: Requires: pywin32
Required-by: -wsebcli, docker, awsebcli

Comment: So it seems awsebcli needs that particular package...?>

Comment: remove these subpackages from your requirements.txt and add only the higher level packages you need.